# Phone crashed after playing 15 or more music files in the normal media player

Tags: lumia, 7.8, mediaplayer

My phone crashed after playing 15 or more music files in the normal media player, it's a Nokia Lumia with WP 7.8.

If I stream music from Onedrive, or when I'm watching video's everything is fine.

Am I the only one who has this problem?

Comment: Did this happen once or is this a reoccurring issue?

Comment: every time after +- 15 music files.